# Need to restart Grails after controller changes

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I'm developing application using `Grails 3.3.10` if I did any change in the controller or service i need to restart Grails to see the effect of that change and this is time consuming , i tried to rebuild the project but still no effect , my IDE is `Intellij`, is there a way to see the effect without restarting Grails ?

Comment: Which version of Intellij?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Intellij `2.2.2019`

Comment: Are you using grails development env? Not sure if related but have a look at: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207602705-Grails-3-not-automatically-hot-swapping-changed-code-after-upgrading-to-2016-1-3

Comment: @SShehab spaces in a file's path will break automatic reloading

Comment: @RahulMahadik , It worked when removed any spaces from the project's name and tried everything worked as expected.